# How do I get Generate Getters/Setters in Eclipse Luna like it was in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: php, eclipse, getter-setter, eclipse-pdt

So last week, I upgraded Eclipse from Juno to Luna. On Juno, the PHP Development Tools that I had installed gave me a `Generate Getters/Setters` Source menu item. This is no longer the case. Do I have to install another plugin for this?

Plugins on Eclipse Juno:

```
plugins $ ls | grep php
org.eclipse.php.core.parser_3.2.0.201402182015.jar
org.eclipse.php.core.parser_3.3.0.201407212212.jar
org.eclipse.php.core_3.2.0.201402182015.jar
org.eclipse.php.core_3.3.0.201407212212.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.core_3.2.0.201402182015.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.core_3.3.0.201407212212.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.daemon_3.2.0.201402182015.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.daemon_3.3.0.201407212212.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.ui_3.2.0.201402182015.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.ui_3.3.0.201407212212.jar
org.eclipse.php.formatter.core_3.2.0.201402182015.jar
org.eclipse.php.formatter.core_3.3.0.201407212212.jar
org.eclipse.php.formatter.ui_3.2.0.201402182015.jar
org.eclipse.php.formatter.ui_3.3.0.201407212212.jar
org.eclipse.php.help_3.2.0.201402182015.jar
org.eclipse.php.help_3.3.0.201407212212.jar
org.eclipse.php.server.core_3.2.0.201402182015.jar
org.eclipse.php.server.core_3.3.0.201407212212.jar
org.eclipse.php.server.ui_3.2.0.201402182015.jar
org.eclipse.php.server.ui_3.3.0.201407212212.jar
org.eclipse.php.ui_3.2.0.201402182015.jar
org.eclipse.php.ui_3.3.0.201407212212.jar
```

Plugins on Eclipse Luna:

```
plugins $ ls | grep php
org.eclipse.php.core.parser_3.3.0.201406110111.jar
org.eclipse.php.core_3.3.0.201406110111.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.core_3.3.0.201406110111.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.daemon_3.3.0.201406110111.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.ui_3.3.0.201406110111.jar
org.eclipse.php.formatter.core_3.3.0.201406110111.jar
org.eclipse.php.formatter.ui_3.3.0.201406110111.jar
org.eclipse.php.help_3.3.0.201406110111.jar
org.eclipse.php.server.core_3.3.0.201406110111.jar
org.eclipse.php.server.ui_3.3.0.201406110111.jar
org.eclipse.php.ui_3.3.0.201406110111.jar
```

I downloaded the .zip from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/pdt/downloads/pdt-Update-3.2.0.201306051924.zip, extracted it, and installed it with Install New Software... It has the following plugins:

```
plugins $ ls 
org.eclipse.php.core.parser.source_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.core.parser_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.core.performance.tests_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.core.source_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.core.tests_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.core_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.core.source_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.core_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.daemon.source_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.daemon_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.ui.source_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.debug.ui_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.formatter.core.tests_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.formatter.core_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.formatter.ui_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.help.source_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.help_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.mylyn.ui_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.server.core.source_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.server.core_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.server.ui.source_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.server.ui_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.ui.source_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.ui.tests_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
org.eclipse.php.ui_3.2.0.201306051924.jar
```

So this functionality was added after June of last year... and then removed before June of this year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I needed [PDT Extensions](http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/)...

...

I don't even remember installing this. Of course, knowing me I'll forget about installing this again, but next I'll find my own question!

Answer (score 0):

You are right ,you gonna need this : [PHP Development Tools 3.3 - Projects - Eclipse](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt/releases/3.3)

That's for Luna.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Consider registering for the site so that you can get reputation. Sadly, I already have this installed. I updated my question.